# Long to nsdate in Objective C

Tags: objective-c, nsdate

I have an char array of 8 bytes which contains current date in long int. How can I convert this into NSDate.

Answer (score 0):

```
[NSDate date]
```

will return the current date.

alternatively, see NSDateFormatter to convert it to a string using format specification and back. beyond that... we'll need to know the internal representation of your char array.

Answer (score 0):

[`NSDate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDate_Class/Reference/Reference.html) offers `initWithTimeIntervalSinceReferenceDate`. The trick is to get the 'reference date' correct. By default, Apple uses 1 January 2001.

Jeff

Answer (score 0):

If you have something like this=> **20100914**

```
char arr[] = {'2','0','1','0','0','9','1','4','\0'};

NSString *dateString = [NSString stringWithCString:arr encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSDateFormatter *df = [NSDateFormatter new];
[df setDateFormat:@"yyyyMMdd"];
NSDate *date = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```